# IONIC httpclient provider, data disappears

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

I wrote this simple HTTP provider:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class GetQueriesProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { console.log('Hello GetQueriesProvider'); }

  getRemoteData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('/TJSON/t22.json').subscribe(data => {resolve(data);}, err => {console.log(err);});
    });
  }
}
```

And here, the component that is using it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Sector } from "../../models/sector.models";
import { GetQueriesProvider } from '../../providers';
@Component({ selector: 'app-sector', templateUrl: './sector.html'})

export class SectorComponent  {
  sectors: any;
  constructor(public getDataService: GetQueriesProvider ) {
    this.getData().then((data) => { this.sectors = data; console.log("1: ", this.sectors);});
    console.log("2: ", this.sectors);
  }
  getData()  { return this.getDataService.getRemoteData(); }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

The problem that I was not able to solve (and I guess it's a trivial one) is that on "Sectors 1", this.sectors is "undefined".

Here the console log:

```
2: undefined

1:
(2) […]
0: Object { area: "Room", domande: (6) […] }
1: Object { area: "FB", domande: (2) […] }
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
```

Can someone help me?

THANKS!

Comment: I think, you are new to promise chain and asynchronous programming. That's creating confusion here. Your promise handlers are async. Please update your question with what are you trying to achieve. So I can help

Comment: ...yes, I am definetely new to promise chain :)

Comment: I want to get json data from a server and to use them inside a component. I got these data from the server (and they are shown in "Sector 0" console log but then ...they disappear in the next step: the console log in "Sector 1" does not show them

Comment: please share component's template

Answer (score 0):

Please change you component code to following

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DOMANDETEST } from '../../assets/domandeTest';
import { DOMANDEDUMMY } from '../../assets/domandeDummy';
import { Sector } from "../../models/sector.models";
import { GetQueriesProvider } from '../../providers';
import { QuestionsProvider } from '../../providers';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-sector',
        templateUrl: './sector.html'
    })
    export class SectorComponent {
        sectors: Sector[];

        constructor(public getDataService: GetQueriesProvider, public questionsService: QuestionsProvider) {
            this.sectors = DOMANDEDUMMY;

            this.getData().then((data) => {
                if (data.length < 2) {
                    this.sectors = DOMANDETEST;
                } else {
                    this.sectors = data;
                }

                this.questionsService.set(this.sectors);
            });
        }

        getData() {
            // return this.getDataService.getRemoteData().then(data => {
            //     this.questionsService.set(data);
            //     console.log("Sectors 0: ", this.questionsService.sctrs);
            //     return data;
            // });

            return this.getDataService.getRemoteData();
        }

        ngOnInit() { }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is stil in place. I revised my question to better show it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @G4m please share sector.html.. as I can see your sectors variable got array of 2 items. Now question is how your template is using it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that it was a sync problem ...and it is. This link reports exactely mu case: https://www.joshmorony.com/dealing-with-asynchronous-code-in-ionic/

So I guess that what I have to do now it's to play with @output() decorator in order to sync my page